# AWS CDK + Appsync nested lambda resolvers arguments

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync, aws-cdk

I'm building a graphql API on AWS using CDK, resolvers are custom lambdas. One type in my `schema.graphql` has got a field with its own inputs. The schema looks something like this.

```
type Output {
  field1: Int!
  field2: String
  field3(input1: String!, input2: String!): Int
}

input MyInput {...}

type Mutation {
  MyMutation(input: MyInput): Output
}
```

Currently I'm only declaring the main `MyMutation` resolver in the CDK script.
The arguments for `field3` are inside `event.info.selectionSetGraphQL`, but are formatted as strings, like `field3(input1: 'str1', input2: 'str2)\n`.

Shouldn't I be able to get them in some sort of `arguments` field as an object as it is for the arguments of the top level `MyMutation`field?
Is this because I'm not using field resolvers properly?

I could not find examples of nested graphql resolvers online. Is there a better way of doing this? Something like Apollo's resolver maps?

Thank you.